# Scala reflection Generic TypeArgs exposure

Tags: java, scala, generics, reflection

I seem to be stuck behind generic type parameters when trying to expose the case accessors in a case class via reflect.

Say I have this:

```
case class test(
  propA: Option[Int],
  propB: String
)
```

I can spit out the model of the test case class but am stuck with this result:

```
{ "subject" : "test",
  "model" : [
    {"field" : "propA", "type" : "A"},
    {"field" : "propB", "type" : "String"}
  ]
}
```

The entries come in as java Fields and I'm using the runtimeMirror to get a ClassSymbol for the class as provided via Field.getType.

```
val parameterizedType = runtimeMirror(field.getType.getClassLoader).classSymbol(field.getType)
```

Then I'm trying to use the selfType to get at the typeArgs but as shown above instead of getting Int I'm getting A and it has me stuck because I'm not as familiar with scala reflect. The type exposure is done with the following line:

```
parameterizedType.selfType.dealias.typeArgs.map(_.toString).mkString
```

I tried to use only Scala reflect to expose the field but the class that I'm inspecting is sometimes a Java class and I ran into issues exposing the fields that way.

Additionally, I've been able to expose the full type path but it still hides the parameterized type:

```
... "propA", "type" : "scala.Option.A"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've worked a bit on https://github.com/miloszpp/scala-ts/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mpc/scalats/core/ScalaParser.scala and we were able to get Option args through a cast, like at line 73 : scalaType.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeRef].args

I'm not sure if that helps, since I don't know what the dealias method does in fact ^^'

Comment: Interestingly, I discovered that the issue was alleviated (kinda) by using Java primitives explicitly as opposed to using Scala primitives. This isn't completely satisfying but presently it is something to pivot against as I continue my investigation.